# NodeJS SSH2 / SFTP Handshake Timeouts

Tags: javascript, node.js, sftp, ssh2

I can connect to the remote SFTP server fine through FileZilla, and have determined the remote server uses the following:

- diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
- ecdh-sha2-nistp521
- aes256-ctr
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp521

I am trying to connect to it using the NPM package ssh2-sftp-client [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client).

My code is the following:

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');

async function main() {
 try {
    let sftp = new Client();

    sftp.on('error', (err) => {
        sftp.errorHandled = true;
        console.log('custom error handler', err);
    });

    await sftp.connect({
        host: 'server',
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        port: 60022,
        readyTimeout: 20000,
        debug: console.log,
        algorithms: {
            kex: [
              "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1",
              "ecdh-sha2-nistp521"
            ],
            cipher: [
              "aes256-ctr"
            ],
            serverHostKey: [
              "ssh-rsa",
              "ecdsa-sha2-nistp521"
            ],
            hmac: [
              "hmac-sha2-256"
            ]
        }
    });

    let result = await sftp.list(`/`);

    console.log(result);

    await sftp.end();
   } catch (err) {
    console.log('catch', err)
  }
}

 main();

process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
console.log('uncaught', err);
process.exit(0);
 })
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Handled Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake undefined
```

I have also tried with the NPM package: SSH2 [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2)

No matter what kind of configuration I try, it always errors out. Does any one have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `readyTimeout`? OpenSSL does some (forced) validation of diffie-hellman key exchange values which could take awhile. Connecting to a server using the curve25519 key exchange however should avoid those validations.

Comment: Did you find any fix for this?

Comment: No, I did not unfortunately. I ended up using an NPM package called yocto-sftp which worked fine.